# Default recordtype setting based on profile in package.xml

Tags: apex, metadata, ant, migration

I am trying to change my default record type for every profile using ANT.

Can someone help me how to retrieve the data using `package.xml`?

Comment: Where are you stuck? What have you tried so far?